Noncommutative analogues of integration
In a paper I’m writing, I take the partial sums of sequences of elements from a monoid.  Much of the paper has analogous theorems for continuous cases using integration.  In particular, one of the proofs involving integration in the paper doesn't utilize the commutative property of addition.  As a result, I was wondering if there are noncommutative analogues of integration which I could use in my paper.

There are some “standard” theory of noncommutative integration, say, the theory of weights in the context of von Neumann algebras, but that doesn’t seem to fit what you’re trying to do. It seems to me in your context the most suitable thing to do is just to copy the definition of Riemann integrals and apply it to a real-variable function with values in a topological “real vector space”, except you don’t require commutativity of addition. No idea if this has ever been done before though.

(Though, to ensure the integral of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ is not the integral of $-f(x)$ from $b$ to $a$ in general, you need to get rid of more assumptions. The easiest way is likely just requiring scalar multiplication to make sense only for positive reals instead of all real numbers.)

@DavidGao The only reason I say the two integrals shouldn’t be equal is because I thought the integral from a to b adds the elements in reverse order relative to the integral from b to a which is only equal given the commutative property.  If this isn’t the case though, then I will remove this assumption.

I think you need to define what addition is then, such that $a "+" b = f(a,b)$ and we can evaluate $f$ with standard sums, products, functions and operators.

@NullSimplex No, no, it is reasonable. I think my earliest comment saying just removing commutativity of addition from the list of axioms of real vector spaces has even more issues anyway. Assuming $0x=0$ is one of the axioms (which follows from the distributivity of scalar multiplication over addition if addition forms a group, not sure about the general case), then distributivity of scalar multiplication over addition already implies addition is commutative (because multiplying by $-1$ gives the additive inverse), so that assumption needs to be weakened anyway.

@NullSimplex Having just scalar multiplication by positive reals is already enough to define Riemann integrals, but even then you get conditions quite close to commutativity, since, say, $x+y+x+y=2(x+y)=2x+2y=x+x+y+y$. I don't know if this actually forces commutativity as well, so if necessary, you might need to weaken the condition even further (by, for example, insisting scalar multiplication to distribute over addition only approximately, under some topology). Also, to ensure this notion of integral is well-behaved, you have to add some additional assumptions on the topology.
